# Using web.py as non blocking http-server

Tags: python, multithreading, web-services, web.py

while learning some basic programming with python, i found web.py. i
got stuck with a stupid problem:

i wrote a simple console app with a main loop that proccesses items
from a queue in seperate threads. my goal is to use web.py to add
items to my queue and report status of the queue via web request. i
got this running as a module but can´t integrate it into my main app.
my problem is when i start the http server with app.run() it blocks my
main loop.
also tried to start it with thread.start_new_thread but it still
blocks.
is there an easy way to run web.py´s integrated http server in the
background within my app.

in the likely event that i am a victim of a fundamental
missunderstanding, any attempt to clarify my error in reasoning would
help ;.) ( please bear with me, i am a beginner :-)

Comment: You shouldn't answer in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a working solution. In a seperate module i create my webserver:

```
import web
import threading
class MyWebserver(threading.Thread):

    def run (self):
        urls = ('/', 'MyWebserver')
        app = web.application(urls, globals())
        app.run()

    def POST ...
```

In the main programm i just call

```
MyWebserver().start()
```

and than go on with whatever i want while having the webserver working in the background.

Comment: I'm having problems killing this program with Ctrl+C, can anyone else confirm?

Comment: Be aware that you might have to add the initialisation of threading during the initialisation of you class like this:  `def __init__(self): threading.Thread.__init__(self)`.

Comment: @puk  Set MyWebServer.daemon = True

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't is be simpler to re-write your main-loop code to be a function that you call over and over again, and then call that from the function that you pass to `runsimple`...

It's guaranteed not to fully satisfy your requirements, but if you're in a rush, it might be easiest.

Answer (score 1):

or just use Tornado, a non-blocking webserver for Python that has an API similar to webpy - 
http://www.tornadoweb.org/

Answer (score 0):

I have also recently used [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/) to queue up tasks that will run in a separate thread.  Your web.py handler just drops a job into a pipe and a completely separate script executes it.  You could have any number of these, and you get the benefits of advanced queue control, etc..