# Can't exit Asynchronous Web.py Web Server

Tags: python, multithreading, httpserver

Going off of this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500935/using-web-py-as-non-blocking-http-server/1872235#comment28474153_1872235), could someone please tell me why I can not kill this program with Ctrl+C:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import web
import threading
class MyWebserver(threading.Thread):
   def run (self):
      urls = ('/', 'MyWebserver')
      app = web.application(urls, globals())
      app.run()

   def POST (self):
      pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
   MyWebserver().start()
```

Comment: BTW, I did try to use Python's Tornado Web Server, but it has little to no documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launch the thread like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import web
import threading

from time import sleep

class MyWebserver(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        urls = ('/', 'MyWebserver')
        app = web.application(urls, globals())
        app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = MyWebserver()
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    while True:
        sleep(100)
```

Comment: Yes, that works. Thank you. Could you please convert it into a minimal working example in case someone wants to borrow it.

Comment: What do you mean? Apply that code into a working example of a simple web.py application?

Comment: Sorry, Minimal working example is a snippet of code whereby if you copy pasted it into a file `foo.py`, it would run successfully

Comment: For example, you are missing `#!/usr/bin/env python`, the import statements `import web` and `from time import sleep`.